# MongoDB, создание новой бд

Tags: node.js, mongodb, база-данных

Хочу создать новую бд Node j
s
подключаюсь таким способом

```
var mongol = new Mongolian(config.get('mongolian:uri')
                           + config.get('mongolian:username') + ":"
                           + config.get('mongolian:password') + "@"
                           + config.get('mongolian:server') + ":"
                           + config.get('mongolian:port'));

var db = mongol.db('mongol_test');
var collection = db.collection('testCollection');
collection.insert({"name":"test"},function(err, doc){
 //Тут проверка
});
```

err возвращает ошибку что я не имею доступа на запись к mongol_test.testCollection,
база mongol_test не создана.
Как сделать так чтобы она создавалась в момент записи в неё коллекции из кода?

Для таблиц local и admin логин и пасс есть.

Ошибка такая

```
[warn] Authentication failed for `admin` @ Mongolian[mongo://"someip":27017]/mongol_test: Error: Server Error: { code: 18, ok: 0, errmsg: 'auth fails' }
{ '0': { [Error: Server Error: { code: 18, ok: 0, errmsg: 'auth fails' }] result: { code: 18, ok: 0, errmsg: 'auth fails' } } }
```

Нашёл решение, проверяю существует ли бд, если нет то вызываю exec и в нём

```
mongo -u username -p password admin --eval "db.getSiblingDB('new_database').addUser('new_user', 'new_password');"
```

Comment: вы запустили бауз данных от имени какого пользователя?  
в параметрах запуска указали путь где будет размещаться база данных? 
какие права на папку где размещена бд?